# Why does this argument error occur when using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm, web-crawler

I'm using scrapy in pycharm. When I run the code below, I receive the following error: `QuoteSpider(scrapy.spiders): TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`

```
import scrapy


class QuoteSpider(scrapy.spiders):
    name = 'quotes'

    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/']
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        title= response.css('title').extract()
        yield {'titletext': title}
```

Comment: "`scrapy.spiders`" is a module - not a class..  inherit from "`scrapy.Spider`" or "`scrapy.spiders.Spider`" instead

Comment: oh , thank you so much , finally it worked ,I should have used capital S for Spider in scrapy.Spider